# Create high trust for SharePoint Add-ins in SharePoint on-premises

Tags: central-administration, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem, farm-admin

I had configured app domain for on-premises ,And I am looking for the next level to generate the Certificate for high trust .

Can any one guide me how can I generate certificate for developers

[image]

Comment: You can get all steps for on-premise SharePoint add-in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901.aspx